# Returning back to the same UIView makes it blank

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm completely new to Objective-C and XCode. In my game, I have a separate UIView which shows up when the user loses the game. There, I have a Try Again button which reloads the previous UIView which runs the game. However, when I go back by pressing, everything looks black and my images edges keep flickering and I cannot see anything. I'm just trying to be descriptive here so that you experienced folks can guess what is happening. Here is the code to pull up the Game Over View.

```
GameOver *gameover = [[GameOver alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[self presentViewController:gameover animated:YES completion:nil];
```

And this is the code that is invoked when the user clicks the Try again button.

```
-(IBAction)tryAgain:(id)sender{
    GameScene *gameScene = [[GameScene alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [self presentViewController:gameScene animated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Your tryAgain method is not going back to the previous view controller, it's creating a new one. The reverse of presenting a view controller is to dismiss it, not to do another presentation. You should read the "View Controller Programming Guide for iOS" -- its a good starting place to learn about view controllers.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the second part just use the line:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
```

You're creating a new instance of GameScene and will not be the same as the first one.

Comment: Thank you. But I want a fresh reload of my previous view. When I implement the code you suggested, my previous timers are all invalidated (which I have done), I want them to start fresh again. I want my previous view to start afresh.

Comment: You should make a `reset` method which resets your game model to its beginning state. Call `reset` in the `-(void)viewWillAppear` method of the GameScene class.